# What is the correct way to use these kind of causative verbs in a sentence?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, causatives, causative-have, causative-get

1. I kindly request you to have all members **participated** in the meeting.
2. I kindly request you to have all members **participate** in the meeting.

What is the correct way to say this sentence? We can use verb past participle form with some things.
ex - I had my car repaired.

Is it possible to use the past participle form of the verb with someone also?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Not grammatical. Easy test: to have someone do something. No past participle.

Comment: 2 is correct, 1 is ungrammatical.

Comment: The members will participate - they won't 'be participated' by someone else. NB _Kindly_ usually comes before the thing you are asking someone to do for you. _Kindly arrange for all members to participate..._